# Find multiple string in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am using

```
Set Fcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To find Value")
```

Now I want to search either for "To find Value" or "To find word" in the same cell. 
How to do it?

Comment: If you have found the cell with "To find Value" why do you what to write the same ("To find Value") in it? This words are already in?

Comment: Yes as from this line I can get "To find value" but now I want to get both "To find value" as well as "To find word".
means if the control find any of them just put the value in fcell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set Fcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To find Value")
If Fcell Is Nothing Then 
   Set Fcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="To find word")
End If

If Not Fcell Is Nothing Then
  ' found, set the value
Else
  ' not found :(
End If
```